# Printing PDF through Phonegap

Tags: pdf, cordova, printing, phonegap-plugins, childbrowser

I would like to print a PDF displayed through a Childbrowser.

Is it possible?

I'm thinking of using the PrintPlugin from Phonegap but the problem is that it only accepts HTML string though I can tweak the plugin a little.

Still I'm a bit clueless on how to approach this issue. 
Any Idea?